# Jenkins: How to get started with "Plot" plugin

Tags: xml, jenkins, plot

I'm new to Jenkins. I want to build a plot using the [plot plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin). What should I do to import XML file into jenkins and generate a result chart source by the xml file? I hope there would be a tutor about how to use the plot plugin
I can now find where to import xml file but how to upload local xml file by using xpath? I don't understand how to use xpath.

Here is the index of XML file:

[image: xml]

[image: data file]

Is this the right expression to build a link between file and jenkins?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't add screenshots, but paste your code into your question.

Comment: You don't upload files through XPath, you use it to select the elements out of an XML file. If your Jenkins job doesn't generate the XML file, then just let a `wget`/`curl` step download it from its source and as a later part of that job include the _plot_ plugin. There are probably tons of XPath tutorials out there that help you understand, what it does. If you have a particular problem with your code then, just post it here.

Comment: @StephenKing first of all, thanks for answering my question. What should I type in "Data series file", it kept saying "'filename.xml' can't be matched".

Comment: Depends on the name of your XML file I would say. You can try it temporarily by putting it manually into the workspace directory.